# После вызова onAdClosed activity переходит по циклу своему в onDestroy

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, admob

Реализовал в приложении загрузку и отображение рекламы `AdMob` типа `Interstitial` / Межстраничный.

Переходы: Запуск -> `ActivitySplash` -> `Activity2` -> `ActivityMain`

Пользователь запускает приложение, смотрит на `ActivitySplash`, в `onCreate()` которого присутствует код

```
AdMobInterstitialLoader adMobInterstitialLoader = new AdMobInterstitialLoader(this);
adMobInterstitialLoader.createAd();
```

Класс **`AdMobInterstitialLoader`**

```
public class AdMobInterstitialLoader {

    private static boolean isInterAdsShowed = false;
    private Activity mActivity;

    // static fields are shared between all instances
    private static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public AdMobInterstitialLoader(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        createAd();
    }

    public void createAd() {
        // create an Ad
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mActivity);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(mActivity.getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));

        AdRequest adRequest;
        // DEBUG or RELEASE
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice(DeviceHash.getMyDeviceHash())
                        .build();
        } else {
            adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
        }

        // load the interstitial ad
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static InterstitialAd getInterstitialAd() {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null
                && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()
                && !isInterAdsShowed) {
            isInterAdsShowed = true;
            return mInterstitialAd;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

После отображения ActivitySplash его я принудительно уничтожаю, чтобы юзер в будущем не смог аппаратной кнопкой `Назад` вернуть. Применяю `finish()`. Грубовато, но ничего другого не придумал пока.

`Activity2` доступно пользователю ТОЛЬКО, если это первый запуск приложения. Поэтому в последующих запусках мы просто его не вызываем, а сразу на `ActivityMain`. Оно загружается, и, когда приложение загрузило полностью `Interstitial` баннер, оно его сразу же отображает (это прописано в методе обратного вызова класса AdMobInterstitialLoader.

В `ActivityMain` чередуются `Fragment'ы`.

Сама проблема.

Запускаю приложение, прохожу по `Activity`, загружается полностью `ActivityMain`, отображается нужный `Fragment`, поверх экрана появляется `Interstitial` баннер, я его закрываю крестиком вверху или аппаратной кнопкой `Назад`. Вместе с баннером закрывается приложение.

По логам видно, что `Activity` и `Fragment` уверенно прошлись по своим жизненным  циклам до `onDestroy()`. Я в замешательстве. Что это может быть ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел я причину возникновения этого явления.

Суть была в методе `startNextActivity()`, реализация которого - примитив. И, естественно, я его свернул, т.к. нечего в нем дорабатывать или улучшать. 
Но, когда появляется нездоровое поведение приложения, начинаешь заглядывать во все углы кода.
Моя проблема была заключена в флаге `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, который я когда-то поставил для некоторых нужд. **И ЗАБЫЛ**

```
// [ START startNextActivity() ]
    private void startNextActivity(Class nextActivityClass) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivityClass);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
// [ END startNextActivity() ]
```

**Этот флаг нужно удалить**

Материал по Intent и флагам:

- ENG - [Intent @ developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
- RU  - [Урок 116. Поведение Activity в Task. Intent-флаги, launchMode, affinity  @ http://startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/190-urok-116-povedenie-activity-v-task-intent-flagi-launchmode-affinity.html)

И будьте внимательны ко всяким своим "Я ща попробую, а потом удалю". Потом может и не наступить! :-)